# Spaces issue in inputbox in Angular/Regex? I need to restrict the first space and then allow user to enter space after first character

Tags: javascript, php, html, regex, angular

I don't want to allow the user to enter space in first character and also restrict user to 3 special characters.

He should be able to press space after the first word. 
I have used REGEX with directive and i am able to achieve most of it. 
The problem is that the user is not able to enter space anywhere in the input box.

help with the regex will be appreciated. 
I have attached a plunker link too. 
https://plnkr.co/edit/05fqqyAn7LRr9vOtri4b?p=preview

```js
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.name = 'World';
});

app.directive("regExInput", function(){
    "use strict";
    return {
        restrict: "A",
        require: "?regEx",
        scope: {},
        replace: false,
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, ctrl){
          element.bind('keypress', function (event) {
            var regex = new RegExp(attrs.regEx);
            var key = String.fromCharCode(!event.charCode ? event.which : event.charCode);
            if (!regex.test(key)) {
               event.preventDefault();
               return false;
            }
          });
        }
    };
});
```

```html
<html ng-app="plunker">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.3.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.14/angular.js" data-semver="1.3.14"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <p>INSane {{name}}!</p>
    
    <div>
      <input type="text" reg-ex-input reg-ex="^[^-\s&</][ws-]*$" />
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: The regex is saying "first character is not a dash, whitespace, `&`, `<`, or `/` and subsequent characters have to be either `w`, `s`, or `-`". Did you mean to use `[\w\s-]*$` for the second part to indicate word characters, spaces, or dashes?

Comment: word characters -
The user will not be allowed to enter &, <, / .  He can enter every other character.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what your regex means, piece by piece

```
^         Beginning of string
[^        Any character that's not one of the following:
  -         Literal '-' character
  \s        Whitespace
  &         Literal '&' character
  <         Literal '<' character
  /         Literal '/' character
]
[         One of the following characters:
  w         Literal 'w'
  s         Literal 's'
  -         Literal '-'
]
*         ...repeated 0 or more times
$         End of string
```

If your intent was for characters after the first one to be either *word characters, spaces or the character "-"*, `[ws-]` should be replaced with `[\w\s-]` since `\w` means "word character" and `\s` means whitespace, not `w` and `s` which are the literal characters.

Comment: ^[^-\s&</][\w\s-]*$ 

With this, I still can't get space after my first character.

Answer (score 0):

Second issue is with the directive itself. The directive is comparing a *single character input* against a regex designed for *the entire string*:

```
if (!regex.test(key)) {
  event.preventDefault();
  return false;
}
```

If you're wanting to test the entire string for validity, doing so in a `keypress` event won't work. The keypress event tells you just what key was pressed, not what the resulting string *will* be if the key press is accepted. Generally, you'll want to validate the entire string against a regexp *after* the value has changed, like in an `input` event. This means you won't be able to cancel key presses, but that would be an unusual UX anyway. For example, backspace and arrow keys are key presses, and evaluating them in context of a regex doesn't make a lot of sense. You may want to consider a *validation* UX, not keypress prevention.

Comment: Thanks for the valuable inputs Jacob.